# SQL query help( Yes,I have already tried nested select)

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

[this is a screenshot of the database I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2QJt.jpg)

So suppose I have a database full of people with their ID numbers along with a year in which they made an entry plus their favorite show in that year. The years are always in the range 2014-2018, but not every one has an entry for each year. How can I count the total number of people who have consistently had the same show as their favorite show over all the years they have been recorded for.

I tried doing a nested selected but I kept getting error. I have checked other SQL related questions here talk about calculate 'change over the years' but none of those answers are compatible with my database and the solution wasn't transferable.

Comment: Can you show the SQL code for what you've "already tried"? It helps us considerably as often we can fix a little mistake instead of having to re-work it from scratch.

Comment: sounds like a `group by` solution... write your DDL and DML and desired result

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You will probably need `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, but without your query I can't really give you any more details (can't see that image either right now).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

See my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/291597/4/0)

```
select id, favorite_show, count(id) as total from people
group by id, favorite_show
having count(id) > 1
```

Comment: This will find all the people who have had the same show as a favorite in more than 1 year, but he wants it in *all* years.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . this gets the people who have only one show:

```
select count(*)
from (select person
      from t
      group by person
      having min(show) = max(show)
     ) p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of different favorite shows someone has, and if that's `1` then they've had the same favorite every time.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT 1
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY person_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT favorite_show) = 1) AS x
```